# project design, am I understanding this correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, design-patterns, dto, entity-framework-core-2.1

I'm a software developer but always  worked on "small" projects/solutions. 
Now I'm trying to create an application from scratch on my own, just to stay in touch with new developments and learn new stuff. I'm trying to use everything I've never used before.
So basically that means I'm developing a c# application, using EF core 2.1 and SQL Server.
I've read a lot of articles online and I learned A LOT already. But I'm still confused because everyday I find a new article using a different approach. 
I would like the opinion of some other developers on what I've got so far. 
First of  all I'm used to WinForms so for now I'll use that as my UI. Just because I can get fast results with it. Afterwards I'll try using ASP.NET Core.
I also want to be able to use an other UI and still be able to use the rest of my solution.
**I have several projects in my solution:**
1. Data: EF Context, DbSets, Migrations 
2. Models: EF models, used in EF Context (nothing more then POCO's)
3. DTO: Objects exposed to the UI (again, classes and properties, nothing more)
4. Mapper: "DTO to Model" and "Model to DTO" 
5. Services: static classes and static methods/functions using all the above, containing the logic. for example GetCustomer uses the EF context class to read the database, gets the model, maps it to a DTO and returns it.
6. UI: binds to the DTO objects and uses the services for every user "action".
That's it, in a nutshell. But am I on the right track?
I've read a lot about IoC but I'm not there yet, but as far as I understand that has "nothing" to do with the above. 
**I do have 1 specific question:** In WinForms there is validation using the IDataErrorInfo interface and for binding I need the INotifyPropertyChanged logic. Where does this belong? I would say in my DTOs but some say a DTO "can't have" any logic.
I'm sorry for the long "question" but I'll appreciate any input to make sure I understand all of this correctly.

Comment: DTO is the short for Data Transfer Object. What you have in 3 are not DTO but VIewModels (models made specifically for the UI). Those *can* implement IPropertyChanged since that's the normal thing to do with the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) pattern

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense. So 2 should be "DataModels" and 3 should be "ViewModels" or something similar... But the idea is still the same, a "service" layer that transforms datamodels to viewmodels, containing all the application logic.

Comment: The correct term for 2 is *Entity* (that's why *Entity* Framework). As advice: I would highly suggest you to invest some time reading on Dependency Injection and making 5 use it and 6 configure the IoC container.

Answer (score 0):

A DTO is usually not intended for presentation. It is intended to send raw data, so they're usually dumb objects and are basically just a bunch of property setters and getters.
A View Model is intended to be sent to a View and a View Model also sends back data to a controller. The ViewModel sometimes takes responsibility for presentation logic.